# export the IBM Docker container images in the registry

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, docker-registry

My aim is to show the portability of docker, and thus being able to export docker container images from the registry/repository to an external docker user.

I can perfectly pull the image from the machine with ICE CLI installed, and authentication (ice login passed), but if I use an other machine, the command `docker pull registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode` or `docker pull registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/kapi/nginx-test`, I get the same result : `authentication required`.

My question is : is it possible to allow some docker images to be available for *everyone*, without authentication ?

I can obviously pull the image from the machine with ice logged in, and then re-export/push it, but it is not the easiest way.

Has anyone an idea, on how to do this ?
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you discovered, IBM Containers currently requires a Bluemix authentication token when connecting to the Bluemix container registry. There is not a public registry where anyone can pull images.

But your idea is interesting and we could look into providing some public images on a public registry. For now, you will need to sign in.

Comment: Where do you get the authentication token from? When I do `cf oauth-token` and copy paste that into a request, say using `curl` or Python's `requests` it always tells me the token is wrong.